# count against predefined enum

Tags: sql, postgresql

I have an enum in psql `('Apple', 'Banana')`
I would like to count the occurrences in a table to find. The expected result is as follows:

```
Count   Fruit
0       Apple
12      Banana
```

Thanks

Comment: `select count(*), fruit from ... .group by fruit` ?

Comment: For zero counts, you'd need all the possible fruits - perhaps from another table or same table with a different where clause.

Answer (score 4):

This will give you counts for each status:

```
SELECT Fruit, COUNT(Fruit) FROM fruits_table GROUP BY Fruit;
```

However, that will not show "0" for null fruit counts:

Use `enum_range(NULL::fruit_enum)` to get an array with all elements of your enum type. Then unnest that array into a rowset, left join it to your `fruits_table` and count rows from that same `fruits_table`.

```
SELECT COUNT(f.*), Fruit
FROM unnest(enum_range(NULL::fruit_enum)) AS Fruit
LEFT JOIN fruits_table AS f USING(Fruit)
GROUP BY Fruit
```

Answer (score 0):

Yes, simply usethe following statement:

`SELECT COUNT (*) FROM your_table GROUP BY Fruit`.

This will count all occurrences of every fruit and summarize in the result table you wrote above.
Hope I could help :)